i am getting the error as ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found
I am getting the error when trying to import matplotlib, ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found.
I have uninstalled the python and anaconda ,but still it is giving me the same error
Please help me to resolve the issue
I tried to reinstall both python and anaconda .I tried to install using pip but it is not working,when i checked for python using where python.exe ,i found that in two different locations.

you have not provided enough information for us to be able to help you.  What is the code?  Is this in a virtual environment? How were things installed?
What steps you took to install the tools, what was the critical code piece ( sounds like just import matplotlib) and what is the exact error?  It sounds like you are windows?  Or is this being done from a jupyter notebook server?

code is simple it is import matplotlib,this is not in virtual environment,i have   uninstalled both python and anaconda ,yes the code is import matplotlib.pyplot as plt,i am using windows ,and trying to execute this code from jupyter notebook,just now i  checked it is working  in IDLE shell without any error

you need to put these details in the question clearly.
